# Clean URL & Image Upload

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I have already posted this in a Drupal forum. I currently have problems with uploading images and using clean urls on the site.

When I upload an image to an article page and then I click refresh to view the page, the image doesn't appear. I check for the image url and an example url would be:

http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/01.jpg

but the image would appear if I modify the url on the address bar to:

http://example.com/?q=sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/01.jpg

I have tried:

- turning on and off clean urls (sometimes the images appear, but then
  they disappear again)
- modifying rewrite rules in the the .htaccess file
- folder permissions

This happened when I uploaded my site to an apache server and the url changes, but doing it locally on my computer, the url don't change.

Comment: so u can enable clean urls in drupal??

Comment: yes, i can enable clean urls

Answer (score 0):

I went on another direction with my photos but I figured it out anyway. All I had to do was to delete the .htaccess file in the site/default/files.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. 

1) Clean URL is turned on i have the following path:
*http://www.site.com/publicfiles/styles/slideshow/public/field/slideshow/image.jpg* it doesn't work


2) Clean url turned off 
*http://www.site.com/?q=publicfiles/styles/slideshow/public/field/slideshow/image.jpg it works of course

3) Clean Url is turned ON
*http://www.site.com/publicfiles/field/slideshow/image.jpg* 

this one works for me, but upload control generates (1) option, not 3rd. I guess that issue is related to missed slash in some folder name or subpath